# Derivative of a integral $|\Psi(\mathbf{r})|^2\int d^3r'\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^{3}}|\Psi(\mathbf{r}')|^2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, differentiation, bose-einstein-condensate

I've been deriving equation of motion for Bose-Einstein condensation (BEC), and I've run into a slight problem while trying to do the derivative of $|\Psi(\mathbf{r})|^2\int d^3r'\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^{3}}|\Psi(\mathbf{r}')|^2$ with respect to $\Psi^*$. This integral is part of a Lagrangian for BEC, and I need to find Euler–Lagrange equation. That means that I need to find:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \Psi(\mathbf{r})^*}|\Psi(\mathbf{r})|^2\int d^3r'\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^{3}}|\Psi(\mathbf{r}')|^2$

I now that $|\Psi|^2=\Psi^* \Psi$ and I think that $\frac{\partial \Psi(\mathbf{r}')^*}{\partial \Psi(\mathbf{r})^*}=\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')$. That means:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \Psi(\mathbf{r})^*}|\Psi(\mathbf{r})|^2\int d^3r'\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^{3}}|\Psi(\mathbf{r}')|^2=\Psi(\mathbf{r})\int d^3r'\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^{3}}|\Psi(\mathbf{r}')|^2+|\Psi(\mathbf{r})|^2\int d^3r'\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^{3}}\Psi(\mathbf{r}')\frac{\partial \Psi(\mathbf{r}')^*}{\partial \Psi(\mathbf{r})^*}$

Finally I get

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \Psi(\mathbf{r})^*}|\Psi(\mathbf{r})|^2\int d^3r'\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^{3}}|\Psi(\mathbf{r}')|^2=\Psi(\mathbf{r})\int d^3r'\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^{3}}|\Psi(\mathbf{r}')|^2+|\Psi(\mathbf{r})|^2\int d^3r'\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^{3}}\Psi(\mathbf{r}')\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')$.

I don't know what to do with the second integral. Delta function should kill that integral and replace $\mathbf{r}'$ with $\mathbf{r}$, but function $\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^{3}}$ whould then be '$\frac{1}{0}$'.

Do you have any idea how I should deal with the second integral?

I hope I was clear enough.

Thank you!

Comment: You have to differentiate with respect to $\Psi(r'')$, not $\Psi(r)$, because $r$ is already involved in the expression you are trying to take the derivative of.

Comment: Use differentiation under the integral sign

Comment: I differentiated with respect to Ψ(″)
 and I got $\delta(−″)\Psi()∫^3'\frac{1}{|−′|^3}\Psi(′)^∗\Psi(′)+\Psi()^∗\Psi()\frac{1}{|−″|^3}\Psi(″)$
. But I can't make the second expression look like the first, since those two expressions need to be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will differentiate with respect to $\Psi(r^{\prime\prime})^{*}$, to get what you already have in the comments

$ \delta(r-r^{\prime\prime}) \Psi(r) \int d^3r^{\prime} \frac{1}{|r-r^{\prime}|^3}|\Psi(r^{\prime})|^2 + |\Psi(r)|^2 \frac{1}{|r-r^{\prime\prime}|^3}\Psi(r^{\prime\prime})$

and then integrate over $r$:
\begin{align}
 \int d^3r  \delta(r-r^{\prime\prime}) \Psi(r) \int d^3r^{\prime} \frac{1}{|r-r^{\prime}|^3}|\Psi(r^{\prime})|^2 + \int d^3r |\Psi(r)|^2 \frac{1}{|r-r^{\prime\prime}|^3}\Psi(r^{\prime\prime}) \\
 =\Psi(r^{\prime\prime}) \int d^3r^{\prime} \frac{1}{|r^{\prime\prime}-r^{\prime}|^3}|\Psi(r^{\prime})|^2 + \Psi(r^{\prime\prime}) \int d^3r |\Psi(r)|^2 \frac{1}{|r-r^{\prime\prime}|^3}
 \end{align}

Now change the integration variable in the last summand from $r$ to $r^{\prime}$.

So from that you can at least conclude that both terms are equal, except for the integration constant that comes when you integrate over $r$. But I do not know how to figure that out since I am not familiar with BEC.